# Implement the kafka in dotnet 7 with domain driven design and add kafkaConsumer as hostedServices

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, apache-kafka, domain-driven-design

i got a question regarding the kafka setup with dotnet 7 core in domain driven design.

As the implementation goes along, i have find out that few things regarding with this kafka implementation, i will listed out as a summary.

1. Everytime start the service, i have to register the topic first.
2. Each topic can set with their own implementation.
3. I can put the producer and the hosted service together, although this is not a good recommendation. But since my service is still small, there is no need to separate it first.

Here is my kafkaCOnsumerWrapper.cs

```cs
public class KafkaConsumerHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger<KafkaConsumerHostedService> _logger;
    private readonly KafkaConsumerWrapper _consumerWrapper;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Func<string, Task>> _topicHandlers;

    public KafkaConsumerHostedService(ILogger<KafkaConsumerHostedService> logger, KafkaConsumerWrapper consumerWrapper)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _consumerWrapper = consumerWrapper;

    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Kafka consumer hosted service is starting");

        _consumerWrapper.Consume(_topicHandlers, cancellationToken);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Kafka consumer hosted service is stopping");

        _consumerWrapper.Dispose();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _consumerWrapper.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Below is my KafkaConsumerWrapper

```cs
 public IConsumer<string, string> _consumer;
    private readonly IAdminClient _adminClient;
    private readonly ILogger<KafkaConsumerWrapper> _logger;
    private readonly IOptions<KafkaOptions> _options;

    public KafkaConsumerWrapper(IOptions<KafkaOptions> options, IAdminClient adminClient,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _options = options;
        var config = new ConsumerConfig
        {
            BootstrapServers = options.Value.BootstrapServers,
            GroupId = options.Value.GroupId,
            AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
        };

        _consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<string, string>(config)
            .SetErrorHandler((_, e) => _logger.LogError($"Error: {e.Reason}"))
            .Build();

        _adminClient = adminClient;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<KafkaConsumerWrapper>();
    }

    public void Consume(Dictionary<string, Func<string, Task>> topicHandlers, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var consumeResult = _consumer.Consume(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                if (consumeResult == null)
                {
                    continue; //try to replay with return;
                }

                var topic = consumeResult.Topic;
                if (!topicHandlers.ContainsKey(topic))
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("No handler found for topic {Topic}", topic);
                    continue;
                }

                var handler = topicHandlers[topic];
                var message = consumeResult.Message.Value;
                handler(message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Error consuming messages from Kafka");
        }
    }
```

```cs
#program.cs
...
builder.Services.AddSingleton<KafkaConsumerWrapper>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAdminClient>(sp =>
{
    var kafkaConfig = sp.GetService<IOptions<KafkaOptions>>().Value;
    return new AdminClientBuilder(new AdminClientConfig { BootstrapServers = kafkaConfig.BootstrapServers }).Build();
});
builder.Services.AddHostedService<KafkaTopicBackgroundService>();
...
```

The service is able to run, but i bumped into one problem which my service got stuck.
And i found out is because it keep checking the consumeResult == null then continue the while loop.

The topic is there, but just no more new item to consume at the moment until the other API call and then produce it.

I try to replace the continue to return, then the service are working fine.
Just i cannot longer to add the handler when there is new produce.

I am not sure which part the logic did wrong, please help to give me some hint which that those part i did wrong, and i can add the debug for it.
Thanks.

Comment: Consumers are meant to be long lived. Create a thread if the while loop is blocking other code

Answer (score 0):

Since you are implementing an IHostedService, your application will never start, since the runtime will wait for the method to finish.

You can start a new thread without waiting or implement a BackgroundService instead, which will already be done for you.

If you want to see how to use an IHostedService for a Kafka Consumer, check out how [KafkaFlow](https://github.com/Farfetch/kafkaflow) does it [here](https://github.com/Farfetch/kafkaflow/blob/master/src/KafkaFlow.Extensions.Hosting/KafkaFlowHostedService.cs) and [here](https://github.com/Farfetch/kafkaflow/blob/a873f3b530ffb8a15a233516287bd471780c55fe/src/KafkaFlow/Consumers/ConsumerFlowManager.cs#L107).